# Rails error handling; reporting, customizing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, error-handling, controller

I was looking into a better way to handle errors and we usually write code that accepts blocks to be done in an successful, outcome.  I inverted that thought, and wrote this up:

```
class SomeVeryBigReportObjectOnWhatWentWrong
   # contains attributes to help format a nice report for humans
   # comes up with a nice backtrace
   # writes to rails log
   # writes to error aggregator (External site)
   # maybe writes to slack depending on error
   # Records the error in another log for developers to view
   # dances and twirls too.
end

class MyTest
  def can?(test, &block)
    return true if test

    if block_given?
      error_report = SomeVeryBigReportObjectOnWhatWentWrong.new("error message for starters")
      yield error_report
    end

    return false
  end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController 

  def action
    page = Page.find(params[:id])
    obj = MyTest.new

    # obj.can?(:read, page)
    return unless obj.can?(false) { | big_error_report |
      big_error_report.context = .... # about 15 lines of this....

      flash[:error] = big_error_report.message
      redirect_to big_error_report.default_error_page
    }

    # back to our regular successful outcomes...

  end
end
```

Pros of this code is that the error handling is indented, allowing people to easily see what's error reporting, it can pull in a lot of the context from the surrounding code and it can customize error report very well.

Make life easier for the next programmer: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-noble-art-of-maintenance-programming/

Cons of the code, is when I look at it, the first "think" I have is

"return" unless "this is false"?  uh? what is the block for?  - confused -

Does this code smell?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is:

- Function `can?` does 2 things: check condition run test or not and run a block. But actually, you may need only 1 of them. Moreover, when you return `false`, what you wanna do for that value, control outside logic?
- `&block` was sent as an explicit parameter, but we haven't used it
- Function name is not clear.

If I refactor this: (Make it clear first)

```
class MyTest
  def run_report
    if block_given?
      yield SomeVeryBigReportObjectOnWhatWentWrong.new("error message for starters")
    else
      # Handle by default
    end
  end
  def can_report?(test)
   # FIXME: I think you're gonna do something here to proceed test
   test
  end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController 

  def action
    obj = MyTest.new

    if obj.can_report?(false)
      obj.run_report { | big_error_report |
        big_error_report.context = .... # about 15 lines of this....

        flash[:error] = big_error_report.message
        redirect_to big_error_report.default_error_page
      }
      return
    end

    # back to our regular successful outcomes...
  end
end
```

Comment: This code happens A LOT all over the site, which is why I combined the two functions together.   I can see the improvement in readability.